# Clearing Radio Buttons to be Reclickable

Tags: jquery, html

This has been Baffling me for a little while and i have tried Several different methods without success.

I am creating a Quiz which uses radio buttons but they wont be visible they will be `checked` by clicking the `li` they reside in, which is working perfectly the issue im having is when a different answer is selected the current `checked` radio gets `unchecked` but it is then unable to be re`checked` if the user was to change their mind and go back to that answer.

I have tried several ways none of which worked including `removeAttr("checked")`, `attr("checked", false)` and just giving each the same name which only allows a single one to be checked but each of these lead to the issue stated above.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cy44mbhq/1/) with the radio buttons visible to show the problem (click through all 4 and try to go back to one it wont recheck)

I could just be missing something obvious so any help would be much appreciated.

Html:

```
<div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="question">A random Question</div>
    <ul class="answers">
        <li>
            <input data-key="a" class="rad" type="radio" />an answer
        </li>
        <li>
            <input data-key="b" class="rad" type="radio" />another answer
        </li>
        <li>
            <input data-key="c" class="rad" type="radio" />and another answer
        </li>
        <li>
            <input data-key="d" class="rad" type="radio" />last answer
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".answers li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("li").children("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).parent(".answers").children("li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).children("input:radio").attr("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to remove the attribute, you just want to set the checked property to false.

Change:

```
$(this).siblings("li").children("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
```

to:

```
$(this).siblings("li").children("input:radio").prop("checked", false);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cy44mbhq/3/)**

My question to you is, why aren't you giving the radio buttons a name attribute, which would group them together?

Comment: +1, Also if you give them a name attribute to group them, you don't need the `prop("checked", false)` line at all, since checking one will automatically check the others.

Comment: I did give them a `name` but when trouble shooting trying to find a solution i removed it from the code above but that also didnt allow the rechecking through the `li` for some reason? and thankyou il accept your answer once enough time has passed

Comment: That's another thing I'd change. Wrap the inputs in `<label>` elements and then bind the labels to be clicked on instead of the list items. Using the labels is also better for accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can use prop:

http://jsfiddle.net/cy44mbhq/4/

```
$(this).children("input:radio").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Thank you, J08691 answered just before you so accepted his answer but +1

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not exactly what you asked for, but this is a much better way to do what you are trying to do *and it doesn't require jQuery!*

### http://jsfiddle.net/Godisgood/cy44mbhq/5/

All I did here was use the `<label>` HTML tag.  You specify the `<label` then `for="` then the `id` of the element that you want to attach it to (a radio or checkbox).  In the end, it should look something like this:

`<label for="a">clickable element goes here</label>`

An alternative way to do this would be to wrap the `<label>` tag around the radio or checkbox element like this:

`<label><input type="radio"/>Text for the label here</label>`

Note: *You may still need to add the `for=` attribute for old and buggy IE browsers.*

*NOTE:  YOU WILL NEED TO RE-STYLE YOUR `LI.SELECTED` CSS CODE, BECAUSE WHEN THE CODE IS WRAPPED IN A `<LABEL>`, THE LI IS NOT CLICKED ON, THE `<LABEL>` IS.*

Hope that helps!